# mleap AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'serializeToBundle'

Tags: python, pyspark, mleap

I am having problems executing the example code from the [mleap repository](http://mleap-docs.combust.ml/py-spark/).  I wish to run the code in a script instead of a jupyter notebook (which is how the example is run).  My script is as follows:

```
##################################################################################
# start a local spark session
# https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html
##################################################################################
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf()

#set app name
conf.set("spark.app.name", "train classifier")
#Run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine (cores X threads).
conf.set("spark.master", "local[*]")
#number of cores to use for the driver process (only in cluster mode)
conf.set("spark.driver.cores", "1")
#Limit of total size of serialized results of all partitions for each Spark action (e.g. collect)
conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "1g")
#Amount of memory to use for the driver process
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "1g")
#Amount of memory to use per executor process (e.g. 2g, 8g).
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")

#pass configuration to the spark context object along with code dependencies
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession(sc)
##################################################################################


import mleap.pyspark

# # Imports MLeap serialization functionality for PySpark
from mleap.pyspark.spark_support import SimpleSparkSerializer

# Import standard PySpark Transformers and packages
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel
from pyspark.sql import Row

# Create a test data frame
l = [('Alice', 1), ('Bob', 2)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
Person = Row('name', 'age')
person = rdd.map(lambda r: Person(*r))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(person)
df2.collect()

# Build a very simple pipeline using two transformers
string_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='name', outputCol='name_string_index')

feature_assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=[string_indexer.getOutputCol()], outputCol="features")

feature_pipeline = [string_indexer, feature_assembler]

featurePipeline = Pipeline(stages=feature_pipeline)

featurePipeline.fit(df2)

featurePipeline.serializeToBundle("jar:file:/tmp/pyspark.example.zip")
```

On executing `spark-submit script.py` I get the following error:

```
17/09/18 13:26:43 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/opringle/Documents/Repos/finn/Magellan/src/no_spark_predict.py", line 58, in <module>
    featurePipeline.serializeToBundle("jar:file:/tmp/pyspark.example.zip")
AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'serializeToBundle'
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I have installed mleap from pypy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Here](https://github.com/combust/mleap/issues/343)

It seems `MLeap` isn't ready for `Spark 2.3` yet.  If you happen to be running `Spark 2.3`, try downgrading to `2.2` and retry. Hopefully, that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by attaching the following jar file when running:

```
spark-submit --packages ml.combust.mleap:mleap-spark_2.11:0.8.1  script.py
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you didn't follow the steps correctly, here http://mleap-docs.combust.ml/getting-started/py-spark.html it says that

> Note: the import of mleap.pyspark needs to happen before any other PySpark libraries are imported.

Hence try importing your `SparkContext` after `mleap`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have just moved `import mleap.pyspark` to the start of the script.  The error remains the same.

Comment: Did you build the package before using it?

Comment: I installed from pypy

Comment: This did not help.